# Why use custome directive when same thing can be done by controller in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am study the tutorial from code school, In the directive tutorial they are giving very simple example of custom directive like 1. Element Directive and 2. Attribute directive. So my question is we can achieve the requirement through the controller, then in which senario we will need custom directive.

**Example Element directive**

**index.html**

```
  <product-title> </product-title>
```

**Custom Directive**

```
app.directive('productTitle', function(){
     return {
        restrict: 'E', // E  for HTML Element
        templateUrl: 'product-title.html'
     };
   });
```

**product-title.html**

```
<h3>
{{product.name}}
<em class="pull-right">   ${{product,price}}</em>
</h3>
```

Same thing can be do in controller

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl"> 
   <h3> {{product.name}} </h3>
</div>
app.controller('ctrl', function(){
    scope.product.name='HP';
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. **Separation of concerns.**

Controllers, architecturally aren't meant for HTML manipulation. They are meant for controlling data, stuff that is displayed on your view.

Whilst you are considering it simple to include that code in controller, which actually is, assume that tomorrow morning a change in the requirement forces you to alter the HTML. What follows is a heavy search and replace activity.

Directives generalize your HTML, they define a seperate layer where you can define custom tags and attributes that can simplify the view you're rendering. Stuffing everything in the controller, will slowly ugly out the whole code base, resulting in difficult code management.

By the way, I guess you'll soon stumble upon the fact that why should i use Services / Factories when i can achieve similar things using controllers. ?? You can check out [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/252288/angularjs-directive-vs-service-vs-controller) answer for more details

Answer (score 0):

You should always create a directive when you see a piece of code that can be reuse.. For example, a DatePicker would be created in a directive.. cause its gonna be useful in more than one place..

But even if its simple, all the logic will be at the same place and you can change it easily (only once) whenever you want. Besides, your source`ll turn more readable once you divide it in more pieces..

Answer (score 0):

In this case the custom directives are mainly for the readability purposes. Custom directive allows you to wrap a chunk of HTML into a different file with a specific purpose. You could for example have a set up wizard for something on your web page. Each custom directive could then represent a separate step of your set up wizard. Instead of having a long HTML doc including all the steps.